# How can I get the metadata of the parameters to a postgresql stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, ado.net

What I have been using, and it used t work, is:

```
string schema;
string procedure;
DbCommand cmd;

// ...

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText =
"SELECT
    parameters.parameter_name,
    parameters.data_type,
    parameters.character_maximum_length,
    parameters.parameter_mode
FROM
    information_schema.routines
JOIN information_schema.parameters 
    ON routines.specific_name = parameters.specific_name
WHERE
    routines.specific_schema = :schemaname
    and routines.routine_name = :paraname
ORDER BY
    routines.routine_name,
    parameters.ordinal_position";
```

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(MakeParameter("schemaname", schema));
cmd.Parameters.Add(MakeParameter("paraname", procedure));
```

But this returns "" (empty string) for the parameter name.

Comment: @eshirvana schema & procedure are both string variables.

Comment: @eshirvana Yes both have valid values. And everything else for each parameter is being returned, just not the name.

Comment: sorry I was under impression that it doesn't return any rows at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty parameter name could be in case if it haven't name:

```
create function foo(bar text, text) returns text language sql as 'select bar||$2';

SELECT                                                                                       
    parameters.parameter_name,
    parameters.data_type,
    parameters.character_maximum_length,
    parameters.parameter_mode
FROM
    information_schema.routines
JOIN information_schema.parameters 
    ON routines.specific_name = parameters.specific_name
WHERE
    routines.specific_schema = 'public'
    and routines.routine_name = 'foo'
ORDER BY
    routines.routine_name,
    parameters.ordinal_position;

┌────────────────┬───────────┬──────────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ parameter_name │ data_type │ character_maximum_length │ parameter_mode │
├────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ bar            │ text      │                     ░░░░ │ IN             │
│ ░░░░           │ text      │                     ░░░░ │ IN             │
└────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS)

Comment: How do you pass a value in then? I guess you could have one parameter with no name, but definitely not 2+. Is that how it works, one of the parameters can have a name of the empty string?

Comment: @DavidThielen You can have any number of parameters without names. I assuming that you are using ADO.NET or something and probably it is not adapted for such things but there is no any problems using plain SQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a7cc1640a2f6b19b59951a4cca554b2a

Comment: @DavidThielen If you encountered troubles with particular function that you can not edit, you could to wrap it into another one with named parameters.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using ADO.NET and it wants each parameter set with AddParameter(name, value) so it needs naming. There's no single call passing them all in, in order. At least not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @DavidThielen `NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("foo", con);  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", "a"); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", "b"); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", "d");` - works fine for me...

Comment: I don't like it because it depends on matching the order in the procedure, but as you pointed out - it works. And if someone wants certainty, then name your parameters.